# Авторизация Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Почему пользователь Firebase остается зарегистрированным в приложении, после того, как я удалил его из консоли firebase?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что пользователь остался в database **Cloud Firestore** или **Realtime Database**?

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Решается отключением Smart Lock на устройстве.